# How do I convert from one data type to another appropriately?

Tags: kotlin, android-layout

I am new to Android Studio. To learn more about Android development using Kotlin, I'm trying to create a simple app that takes in a gross salary and calculates the net salary using the tax rate.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3ncM.jpg) is an image of what the app looks like.

After entering the gross salary, the app crashes.

The code in *activity_main.xml* is shown below:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSalaryLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Salary($)"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSalary"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Enter your salary here"
        android:textColorHint="@color/light_blue"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvSalaryLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvSalaryLabel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvSalaryLabel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTaxLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tax Rate(%)"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvSalaryLabel"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvSalaryLabel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tvSalaryLabel"
        android:textSize="20sp"
         />


    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/taxSlider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/etSalary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvTaxLabel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvTaxLabel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/etSalary"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNetSalaryLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Net Salary($)"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTaxLabel"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvTaxLabel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tvTaxLabel"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNetSalary"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvNetSalaryLabel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/taxSlider"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/taxSlider"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvNetSalaryLabel"/>
```

The code in MainActivity.kt is shown below:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.transition.Slide
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.slider.Slider

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var salaryEditText: EditText
    private lateinit var taxRateSlider: Slider
    private lateinit var netSalaryEditText: EditText

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        netSalaryEditText = findViewById(R.id.etNetSalary)
        taxRateSlider = findViewById(R.id.taxSlider)
        salaryEditText = findViewById(R.id.etSalary)

        taxRateSlider.stepSize = 5F
        taxRateSlider.valueFrom = 0F
        taxRateSlider.valueTo = 100F
        taxRateSlider.isTickVisible = false

        taxRateSlider.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->
            calculateTax()
        }

    }

    private fun calculateTax(){
        //calculate tax logic
        var grossSalary: Int = salaryEditText.toString().toInt()
        var amount: Float = (taxRateSlider.value / 100) * grossSalary
        netSalaryEditText.setText(amount.toString())
```

If I try to slide the Slider, the app crashes instantly.**Logcat says the error is at line 38**. That is the 3rd line in CalculateTax() which says:

`var amount: Float = (taxRateSlider.value / 100) * grossSalary`

I am really struggling to find any useful tutorials on Android development using Kotlin(and xml) so I would appreciate any references(paid and unpaid).

I expected to get a net salary value when I slide the Slider

Here is the error log stacktrace:

```
2023-03-25 11:15:37.010 18480-18480 AndroidRuntime          com.example.salarytaxcalculator      E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.salarytaxcalculator, PID: 18480
                                                                                                    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{211f536 VFED..CL. .F...... 382,248-1027,349 #7f0800b2 app:id/etSalary}"
                                                                                                        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
                                                                                                        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
                                                                                                        at com.example.salarytaxcalculator.MainActivity.calculateTax(MainActivity.kt:37)
                                                                                                        at com.example.salarytaxcalculator.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:30)
                                                                                                        at com.example.salarytaxcalculator.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$dE2aYSX4M6OhcYfG0v8CNzNK10M(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at com.example.salarytaxcalculator.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onValueChange(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at com.example.salarytaxcalculator.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onValueChange(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.dispatchOnChangedFromUser(BaseSlider.java:2299)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.snapThumbToValue(BaseSlider.java:2051)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.snapActiveThumbToValue(BaseSlider.java:2036)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.snapTouchPosition(BaseSlider.java:2032)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.onTouchEvent(BaseSlider.java:1915)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.slider.Slider.onTouchEvent(Slider.java:42)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12513)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:70)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
2023-03-25 11:15:37.010 18480-18480 AndroidRuntime          com.example.salarytaxcalculator      E      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
                                                                                                        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
                                                                                                        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:177)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:7166)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7218)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:690)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2023-03-25 11:15:37.075 18480-18480 Process                 com.example.salarytaxcalculator      I  Sending signal. PID: 18480 SIG: 9
```

Comment: **Logcat says the error is at line 38** Can you show us the error log stacktrace? It should show the specific Exception you are encountering.

Comment: @Enowneb I have edited in the error log stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your provided error log, the actual problem is here:

> ```kotlin
> var grossSalary: Int = salaryEditText.toString().toInt()
> ```

If you just simply call `salaryEditText.toString()`, as logged in the error stacktrace, it is actually returning the following value, not the content inputted in `salaryEditText`:

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{211f536 VFED..CL. .F...... 382,248-1027,349 #7f0800b2 app:id/etSalary}
```

And the correct way to get the String content of your `salaryEditText` is:

```kotlin
salaryEditText.text.toString()
```

Therefore, the correct code should be like this:

```kotlin
var grossSalary: Int = salaryEditText.text.toString().toInt()
```

And note that with the above code, you have to make sure only Number is inputted in `salaryEditText`. It may be better for you to perform checking on it:

```kotlin
var grossSalary: Int = try {
    salaryEditText.text.toString().toInt()
} catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
    // Set a default value here if the input value is invalid
    0
}
```